# Transferring data from bluetooth to the android app

Tags: android, arduino

I have the following code in android studio, we have a arduino with a bluetooth module HC-05 and we are trying to send a data from a sensor via the bluetooth to the android app:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temperature);
    btnOn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.measure);
    sensorView0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp);
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    CheckBlueToothState();

    btnOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                sendData();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Start Measuring", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}

void openBT() throws IOException {
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard //SerialPortService ID
    mmSocket = mmDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    mmSocket.connect();
    mmOutputStream = mmSocket.getOutputStream();
    mmInputStream = mmSocket.getInputStream();


    bluetoothIn = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == handlerState) {                                     //if message is what we want
                String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;                                                                // msg.arg1 = bytes from connect thread
                recDataString.append(readMessage);                                      //keep appending to string until ~
                int endOfLineIndex = recDataString.indexOf("%");                    // determine the end-of-line
                if (endOfLineIndex > 0) {                                           // make sure there data before ~
                    String dataInPrint = recDataString.substring(0, endOfLineIndex);    // extract string
                    int dataLength = dataInPrint.length();                          //get length of data received

                    if (recDataString.charAt(0) == '*')                             //if it starts with # we know it is what we are looking for
                    {
                        String sensor0 = recDataString.substring(1, endOfLineIndex);             //get sensor value from string between indices 1-5


                        sensorView0.setText( sensor0 );    //update the textviews with sensor values

                    }
                    recDataString.delete(0, recDataString.length());                    //clear all string data
                    dataInPrint = " ";
                }
            }
        }
    };

    beginListenForData1();
    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    myHandler.postDelayed(mMyRunnable, 1000);//Message will be delivered in 1 second.


    // myLabel.setText("Bluetooth Opened");

}


void beginListenForData1() {


    stopWorker = false;
    readBufferPosition = 0;
    readBuffer = new byte[1024];
    workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytes;

            // Keep looping to listen for received messages
            while (true) {
                try {
                    bytes = mmInputStream.read(buffer);            //read bytes from input buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(buffer, 0, bytes);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity via handler
                    bluetoothIn.obtainMessage(handlerState, bytes, -1, readMessage).sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    });

    workerThread.start();
}


private Runnable mMyRunnable = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        //Change state here
    }
};




private void CheckBlueToothState() {
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
    } else {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            } else {
            }
        } else {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);


        }
    }
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
    if(pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            if(device.getName().equals("HC-05")) {
                mmDevice = device;
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            openBT();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Connection Failure", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();};
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
        {CheckBlueToothState();

        }

    }
}


void sendData() throws IOException
{
    String msg = "1";
    msg += "\n";
    mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    //myLabel.setText("Data Sent");
}

void sendData0() throws IOException
{
    String msg = "0";
    msg += "\n";
    mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
    //myLabel.setText("Data Sent");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    try {
        sendData0();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        closeBT();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //System.exit(0);
    this.finish();

}

void closeBT() throws IOException
{
    stopWorker = true;
    mmOutputStream.close();
    mmInputStream.close();
    mmSocket.close();
}
```

}

The code works for the second time only, so when i press the button in the app for the first time it does not show the data, but when i press it at the second time it shows the data, why is that happening?

Comment: `Transferring data from bluetooth to the android app`. ??? I think you want to transfer data from Arduino sketch to Android app using a bluetooth connection. Both devices have a 'bluetooth module'.

Comment: Probably the first time mmOutputStreamm is stii null and you havel a null pointer excelption which you will not see as that catch block if empty. Put the normal code In it a a toast to warn the user.

Comment: I'm a beginner user in android studio and i dont understand null pointer. Can you explain what is it and how to fix it?

Comment: Just google a little bit around on this site. Every day people have null pointer problems.